# Unable to connect to Redis

Tags: spring-boot, redis, render

I am trying to connect the REDIS instance and postrgresql instance to the spring boot backend web service all hosted in the RENDER hosting site.

I connected postgresql instance using internal url and tried the same with redis internal url using application properties but the redis is connecting to the backend webservice.

Redis internal url is in the format redis://host:port
In application properties file I gave

```
spring.session.store-type=redis
spring.redis.url = redis://host:port
```

On deploying the site, when I try to hit the endpoint Unable to connect to Redis message is logged.
I tried connecting from my local machine using redis-cli to the RENDER redis instance using username and password but when I tried to use internal url it is not working.